# Facing problem in downloading the image in Vue js application

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on Vue.js application and trying to download an Image on the page but I am getting `download, Failed-Network error`. Below is my sample code and error screen shot is also attached for reference.

```
<img ref='img' id='image' :src="image" class='img-fluid' :style='filters' data-original-width='760' data-original-height='476'>

<button class="btn btn-success" @click="download"> Download </button>

 download() {
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = document.getElementById("image").getAttribute("data-original-width");
            canvas.height = document.getElementById("image").getAttribute("data-original-height");

            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            // ctx.filter = this.filters.filter;

            var img = new Image();
            img.src = this.image;
            img.onload = function() {
                ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                const anchor = document.createElement('a');
                anchor.href = canvas.toDataURL();
                anchor.download = 'filtered.png';
                anchor.click();
            };
    }
```

[image: downloadError]

Comment: Can you create af fiddle for this experiment ?

Comment: I think in your `img.src` declaration you need `this.$refs.image` instead of `this.image`